# Cannot connect to database server

Tags: asp.net, connection, informix

When I run:

`if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();`

I Get the the following exception:

**ERROR [08004] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Cannot connect to database server** ...

I don't know what the problem is; can you tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.odbc.doc/odbc186.htm) error 08004 means:

> Data source rejected establishment of connection

So maybe your credentials are incorrect or some ip restrictions are in place.

Comment: **Edit:
i fix the problem:
i test this application and i find a big mistake (wrong connection string),,and the right one is written in app setting section , when i try to correct some problems in the the layer which contain the connection i modify it to to connect to the connection string.**